# app.use(session()) gives err is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am completely new to node js. This am doing for learning purpose. I am using passport js to validate username and login it works fine.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, function (username, password, done) {
console.log(username,password);
User1.collection('mydb1', function(err, collection) {
    if (!err) {
        collection.findOne({
            username:username
        }, function(err,user) {
            console.log(user);
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }

            if (user.password != password) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Invalid password' 
                });
            } else {
                return done(null, user);
            }
     })
}});
```

**configuration**

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**Authentication**

```
app.post(
    '/',
    passport.authenticate(
        'local',
        {
            successRedirect: '/success',
            failureRedirect: '/loginerror'
        }
    )
);
```

in `/success` i want to display the username in another page i try to access username like 
`request.user.usernmame`

```
app.get('/success', function(request, response){
    response.send('ok');
    console.log(request.user.username);
});
```

But i got the following Error message in console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'usernmame' of undefined
at Object.app.post.passport.authenticate.successRedirect [as handle] (D:\nod
ejsmodule\mongodb\server.js:114:25)
at next_layer (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:103:13)
 at Route.dispatch (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:107:5)
 at D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:213:24
 at Function.proto.process_params (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\r
 outer\index.js:286:12)
 at next (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:207:19)
 at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib\
 middleware\authenticate.js:314:9)
 at SessionStrategy.authenticate (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib\s
 trategies\session.js:67:10)
 at attempt (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticat
 e.js:337:16)
 at Layer.authenticate [as handle] (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib
 \middleware\authenticate.js:338:7)
```

if i add `app.use(session({ secret: 'anything',saveUninitialized: true,resave: true }));` in configuration part i got following Error message in console

```
ReferenceError: err is not defined
at passport.use.LocalStrategy.usernameField (D:\nodejsmodule\mongodb\server.
js:67:10)
at pass (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:353:9)
at Authenticator.deserializeUser (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib\
authenticator.js:358:5)
at SessionStrategy.authenticate (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib\s
trategies\session.js:49:28)
at attempt (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticat
e.js:337:16)
at Layer.authenticate [as handle] (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\passport\lib
\middleware\authenticate.js:338:7)
at trim_prefix (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:254
:17)
at D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:216:9
at Function.proto.process_params (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\r
outer\index.js:286:12)
at next (D:\nodejsmodule\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:207:19)
```

Comment: Try with "username" instead of "usernmame"

Comment: Sorry for that this is small typo while paste. any how i tried the same error still

Comment: I think you are redirecting via http post and trying to get the info via http get, so... The req info is empty. Sorry i'm with my mobile and can't help more. The fact is req IS defined, it's user the undefined (req.user.username).

Comment: Try to do console.log('myreq',request); and after try to change from app.get to app.post

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem before. I think, that you have the same too.

The reason for it, that Passport can't get data from POST body. For fix it, you must provide `req` and `res` variables of Express to Passport.

Try wrap your code with auhtentication with (req, res):

```
app.post(
    '/',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/success',
        failureRedirect: '/loginerror'
    })(req, res)
);
```

For better vision I will write it like this:

```
app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local')(req, res));
```

Comment: i tried 'req is not defined' in console. what to do?

Comment: You must have access to variables ```req``` and ```res```. Read about this more here - http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

Comment: i am not Fixing the issue. if you find pls update for appreciation +1

Answer (score 1):

Try to do console.log('myreq',request); and after try to change from app.get to app.post. sorry im with Mobile versión.

Something like:

app.post('/success', function(request, response){ response.send('ok');
console.log('myreq',request); console.log(request.user.username); });

Comment: yes i also tried like this. response.send('ok'); console.log('myreq',request); console.log(request.user.username); everything is not worked.

Comment: i am not Fixing the issue. if you find pls update for appreciation +1

Comment: Next week i will have my pc and i will give a try for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do console.log('myreq',request); and after try to change from app.get to app.post. sorry im with Mobile versión.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. i tried like app.post('/success'...). but both consoles are not fired.

Comment: Try with app.get and tell me if the log is showing something

Comment: this are the results 'myrequest': [object Object]
'myrequest req.user': undefined

Comment: It's necessary to check this [object] with something like for (v in request) console.log(v+'= '+request[v]);

Comment: look this 'err is not defined' why i get this can you experienced like this(look second error message in my question)